# Mr. Fontsy Pants

Tags: cipher, visual

I asked a graphic designer friend to look over a draft of a job application I'd put together. He looked it over and quickly said, "There's one big thing wrong with this."

I asked what it was and he gave me the note below.

What specifically did he not like about my draft?

### [image]

Another note (HINT):

Since I couldn't interpret his note, he gave me another one:

> [image]

Comment: Could you put this in a Google Doc?

Comment: so far, no. the fonts don't transfer over, so the necessary info is lost.

Comment: This is all I got so far: (ROT13) Rhn ftr ghm ux tuex mh cnwzx t uhhd ur bml vhoxk unm rhn vtg vxkmtbger cnwzx ur bml mrixytvx.

Comment: @user477343 - I don't think that's heading anywhere, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I know, I was only joking :P. In other words, I am finding this puzzle a little difficult. Perhaps a hint would be nice? :P **Edit:** Sorry, don't mean to sound rude.

Comment: Hint added - another note from the roommate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Answer:**

> Comic Sans

**How I got it:**

Step 1:

> The text of the message does not matter at all. What matters is font choice. If you assign each font a letter, you'll end up with: 
>  abcdefgchifabcjkeaedlcmieabcgcihmdnfkeoadqpsdemifekahcqkllcemcmjkhhcftlcf
>  The hint is very useful in verifying some of the more difficult letters.

Step 2:

> The puzzle is a simple substitution cipher. As you're going through it, you'll need to work out the proper spacing for the code.
>  abc defgch if abc jkea edlcm ie abc gcihm dn fkeo adqps dem if eka hcqkllcemcm jkh hcftlcf

Step 3:

> The cipher reveals the hidden phrase:
>  "the answer is the font named in the weird al song tacky and is not recommended for resumes"

Step 4:

> Go watch Weird Al's song "Tacky" and listen for font names. 
>  Or just click [this link](https://youtu.be/ESatrlWVgAo?t=79) and go to the exact moment of the song in which it is said.

Fun puzzle @Stidgeon, I really enjoyed it.